# ANTLR4 Literal for HEX string containing new line

Tags: python, antlr, antlr4

I was trying to parse a SVF file for JTAG and I found this problem:

I have to parse an hexadecimal value that can contain spaces and new lines, but I need to have also numbers (without spaces).

I have line comments and white spaces are irrelevant so I used these lexical rules:

```
COMMENT : ('!' | '//') .*? '\n' -> skip ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

The numbers and hex definitions are:

```
hexLiteral : HEX | NUM ;

NUM : [0-9]+ ;
HEX : [0-9a-f]+ ;
```

This works if the input has no new lines or spaces in hex strings, eg:

```
hexBlock returns [val: str] : '(' hexLiteral ')' {print($hexLiteral.text)}
```

Run over `(0af3)` does the job.

But I need to match and extract also strings like `(0a3f 10 e2)` returning `0a3f10e2`.

My first idea was to use:

```
hexLiteral : (HEX | NUM) hexLiteral? ;
```

But the parsing for the block results in `mismatched input '10' expecting ')'`.

Comment: What does (10) mean? is it 10 in decimal or 10 in hex (16 in decimal)?  If the latter, then I think hexLiteral should be `HEX+`, right?

Comment: 10 is hexadecimal, but since the tokenizer act before parsing it is marked as integer (upper case rules are for tokens), if I reorder the definitions of HEX and NUM on the other hand I get all numbers marked as HEX even when they shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make 2 opposite things to work together:

1. You want to ignore whitespaces and I guess you use them to separate tokens in your language.
2. You want whitespaces in some of your tokens too.

Instead of trying to make your grammar accepting all kind of ws/digit combinations I recommend to collect the individual parts as normal numbers and then in the semantic phase after the parse run you can examine your parse tree and put all tokens together that are supposed to build a single unit.

Comment: My problem is that `(ab01 01)` does not match my grammar because skipped characters, this is interpreted as `'(' HEX NUM ')'` so it does not match and gets skipped; i found  that `(HEX | NUM)+` as hex literal works even though it should be the same